# How to avoid race conditions in BeginInvoke()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, begininvoke

I have a button in a browser frame (CEFSharp). If I click the button I can handle the click indirect with my C# method `DoSomething()`. `DoSomething()` is not called in the "Main-Thread". `DoSomething()` should call `_api.CallAnExportedComFunction()` in the "Main-Thread" (some functions in AutoCAD). `_api.CallAnExportedComFunction()` is an exported COM function. To call `_api.CallAnExportedComFunction()` in the "Main-Thread" I am using `BeginInvoke()`. `_api.CallAnExportedComFunction()` should not be called in parallel.

If I press the button one time everything works correct. If I press the button some times very slow everything works correct.

If I press the button very rapidly in a row  `_api.CallAnExportedComFunction()` is called in parallel but it should not. I tried to use `lock()` inside of BeginInvoke but it does not work.

So Why is `_api.CallAnExportedComFunction()` called in parallel and how can I avoid it? Why have the Action's in BeginInvoke() race conditions? Does `lock()` only works between two DIFFERENT threads?

I am using the integer ix to count up and down. It should never reach the value 2. But it does. If I replace the COM-call `_api.CallAnExportedComFunction()` with an http request or a sleep it seems that I have no race-conditions.

```
private object _lock = new object();
private int ix = 0;

private void DoSomething()
{

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"ThreadAny: {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

    // When initializing the Plugin _uiDispatcher.Dispatcher is set to System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher
    _uiDispatcher.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            ++ix;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"+ThreadMainBeginInvoke: {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} => ix={ix}");

            _api.CallAnExportedComFunction();

            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            //var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
            //var b = client.DownloadData("http://www.google.de");

            --ix;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"-ThreadMainBeginInvoke: {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} => ix={ix}");

        }
    }), null);
}
```

> **OUTPUT**:
>   ThreadAny: 19
>   +ThreadMainBeginInvoke: 1 => ix = 1
>   -ThreadMainBeginInvoke: 1 => ix = 0
>   ThreadAny: 9
>   +ThreadMainBeginInvoke: 1 => ix = 1
>   ThreadAny: 27
>   **+ThreadMainBeginInvoke: 1 => ix = *2***
>   -ThreadMainBeginInvoke: 1 => ix = 1

Unfortunatly I am not a COM expert and the COM code is not mine but If it is important I can try to add some code.

Comment: lock is re-entrant on the same thread, so it does nothing at all.  Simply acknowledge that you can't allow the user to click the button at a high rate.  Set its Enabled property to false.  Back to true at the end of the invoked code.  Or use Semaphore, it is not re-entrant.  Do beware that there is another major red flag, it is not obvious how you can have ui code on more than one thread.  It is [very, very risky](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/).

Comment: "lock at the same thread does nothing". That helps me to understand. But it brings me to an other question. Does BeginInvoke() interrupt the running code in the main-thread?

Comment: @koalabruder No, it doesn't "interrupt" anything.  It schedules the code you have provided to run as soon as the UI thread finishes all of the other work it has been given up until that point.